# Open graph action "post" keeps being rejected for grammatical error

Tags: action, grammar, facebook-opengraph

I am creating a Facebook open graph action called "post." It only appears in the past tense, and you can see the screenshot below for how it's worded. I can't find any grammatical problems with this. Is anyone else able to weigh in on why this is getting rejected?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTfJf.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, you MUST provide a present and a past tense (even though in this case, the present tense makes no sense). No matter, the present tense version won't ever be displayed as long as your start_time == end_time for the action.

So you need to submit:
present: 'is posting'
past: 'posted'

This requirement is being reviewed but thats the state of play at the moment.